# How to get select values without removing duplicates used inside inner query using oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need the resultset with duplicates produced in the inner query, as of now i am getting the select values as one result for duplicates inside inner query.

Current working query

```
select listagg(column3, '') within group (order by column3) 
from table_name
where column3 in ('ABA', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'ABD', 'ABF', 'ERF', 'AGR', 'LFS', 'BOE') and
      column1=384
```

getting the result as

```
ABAABCABFERFLFSBOE
```

based on column3 and column1 condition available in the table i will print all row values of column3 in same row without appending any gap or extra characters

But i need actual result as

```
ABAABCABCABFERFLFSBOE
```

I need it get the result twice as duplicates inside the in query. Can anyone help me in this query without removing duplicates by printing as the condition is true and duplicates inside the inner query.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, query you wrote *will* work as you'd want it to.

It appears that one of the rows whose `column3 = 'ABC'` doesn't have `column1 = 384` which caused one of `ABC` appearances to be removed from the result.

How not to remove those duplicates? Perhaps by using a join?

```
SQL> with tn (col1, col3) as
  2    (select 384, 'ABC' from dual union all
  3     select 111, 'ABC' from dual union all
  4     select 384, 'FFF' from dual union all
  5     select 384, 'DDD' from dual
  6    )
  7  select listagg(a.col1, '') within group (order by null) result
  8  from tn a join tn b on a.col3 = b.col3
  9  where a.col3 in ('ABC', 'ABC', 'FFF')     --> simulating your IN list
 10    and b.col1 = 384;

RESULT
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
111384384

SQL>
```

Comment: is there any way not to remove

Comment: Join might help. I've added an example; have a look, please.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `left join` for this purpose, instead of `in`:

```
select listagg(t.column3, '') within group (order by t.column3) 
from (select 'ABA' as val from dual union all
      select 'ABC' as val from dual union all
      select 'ABC' as val from dual union all
      select 'ABD' as val from dual union all
      select 'ABF' as val from dual union all
      select 'ERF' as val from dual union all
      select 'AGR' as val from dual union all
      select 'LFS' as val from dual union all
      select 'BOE' as val from dual
     ) v left join
     table_name t
     on v.val = t.column3
where v.column1 = 384;
```

Comment: in my case i don't use static values like i mentioned in my question as 'ABA', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'ABD', 'ABF', 'ERF', 'AGR', 'LFS', 'BOE'. It will be dynamically using the values from list using spring jpa

Comment: for understanding i have mentioned it, but i am passing list as parameter using spring jpa

Comment: can you suggest me inside from statement how to use in (:param)